# Illustrator - How do I change the canvas color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Illustrator crashed due to an error in the preferences (never saw that one before). Of course, I had to reset all of the preferences. I don't remember how to change the overall background color. I don't like working with the default dark grey. What is the command/dialogue box to reset?

Answer (score 1):

The background colour is controlled by the Brightness selection and the Canvas Color choice in the User Interface preferences.

```
Preferences > User Interface
```

[image: Preferences > User Interface]